# Prevent html page scrolling to widget automatically on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok So I have a page I am building and it has a widget in an iframe tag:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/widget/booking.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  initTaxicodeWidget("taxicode - widget", "wolverhamptontaxis.co.uk ");
</script>
```

```html
<iframe id="taxicode-widget" src="blank.html" frameborder="0" style="position: absolute; top: -9999em; visibility: hidden;" onload="this.style.position='static'; this.style.visibility='visible';"></iframe>
```

When everything has finished loading, the page automatically scrolls down to the booking form widget and places a cursor ready for input... I don't want the page to scroll down to it unless the user scrolls down. How can I stop this... 
My jquery and javascriptaren't great so as much detail as possible please :)

Comment: Stop focusing the input?

Comment: I should add this happens in edge, chrome and on android devices.

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood my comment. Have you tried removing code that focuses the input text box? It might help if we actually saw the code for `initTaxicodeWidget()`.

Comment: See link posted in Andrey Telesh's answer for code in widget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so after much deliberation I have re-visited my code and established that I just needed to add a src attribute (that points to a blank html) to the iframe and it prevents the issue from happening without affecting loading speed.
I have edited the code above to reflect this

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<iframe id="taxicode-widget" frameborder="0" style="position: absolute; top: -9999em; visibility: hidden;" onload="setTimeout(function (){this.style.position='static'; this.style.visibility='visible';}, 1000);"></iframe>
```

This will delay returning the position of iframe for 1 second. And it's scrolling bottom because the autofocus attribute installed at the first input element of your widget in iframe.

Comment: this stops the whole widget fromloading at all :(

Comment: Try to remove _visibility: hidden_ at all. Some browsers don't want to load iFrames if they are hidden or it's opacity is zero

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately it is just not loading the widget at all when using that code edit

Comment: The problem is that your onload attribute triggers on blank.html is loaded on it and styles have been replaced before you're loading widget`s page. Set frame.onload  = function() {/*CODE*/} in your initTaxicodeWidget function right after the taxicodeWidget = document.getElementById(widget);

Comment: Thank you Andrey but I have solved the problem already...I have altered the code to reflect this as stated in my own answer